# Shadow-only material (Shadow Catcher)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, hdri

I have a scene where I'm using a HDRI image for the background (and have a separate sun inside). The HDRI doesn't contain only sky, but also a bit of the ground. The problem with placing objects in the environment is that they don't cast shadow to the ground (as the ground is part of the hdri).

I am thinking about making a material to put flatly on the ground that would be:
a) generally transparent
b) giving a grey tint to the places where the objects shadows would be

How would I set a material like this? Or is there maybe a better way to achieve the shadows?

Note: I don't care about it being fully photorealistic with the ground materials etc (as this is obviously impossible), but rather would like to have a rough shadow where it should be.

[image: the object on the background]

Comment: maybe you are looking for shadow catcher: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OOCjR5s9EQ

Comment: precisely! Feel free to promote your comment to an answer

Comment: sorry I thought you were using Eevee, actually in Cycles it's even easier, just enable the Shadow Catcher option

Comment: Yeah, I found the option once I knew what to look for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cycles you can simply select your plane and enable the *Shadow Catcher* option in the *Object* panel:

[image]

In Eevee you can use the trick explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OOCjR5s9EQ) by CG Top Tips, which consists on the following node setup:

- *Diffuse RGB > (Converter >) Shader to RGB > ColorRamp > (Factor) Mix Shader*
- *Diffuse BSDF > (Shader) Diffuse BSDF*
- *Transparent BSDF  > (Shader) Diffuse BSDF*
- *Mix Shader > Output*

[image]

Don't forget to choose *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* and *Shadow Mode > Opaque* in the material *Settings*.